# expressjs rejecting post request (400 bad request) when content-type and content-ecoding headers are sent together

Tags: express, http-post, gzip, content-type, content-encoding

````
app.use( 
    express.text({type: 'text/xml'}), 
    express.json({type: 'application/json'}),
    other middlewares...) ```
````

Post method headers:
{
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'content-length': '1082',
  'content-encoding': 'gzip',
  'content-type': 'text/xml',
  accept: '*/*',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip',
  origin: 'chrome-extension://sxwwwwagimdiliamlcqswqsw',
  'accept-language': 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7'
}

````
Also I have tried express.raw with a wildcard for the type, but the response 
is always 400.

```express.raw({type:'*/*', inflate:true}), (req, res, next)=>{console.log(req.body); next() },```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding this [nodejs](https://nodejs.dev/get-http-request-body-data-using-nodejs) tutorial I was able to fix it.
The key is not to use any express parser, and use vanilla nodejs instead.

```
  app.use( 

        (req, res, next)=>{
            let data = []
            req.on('data', chunk => {
                data.push(chunk)
            })
            req.on('end', () => {
                req.body = data.toString()
            });
            next()
        }
    )
```